# Scan S3 bucket, upload only zip files into S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Here's my code to upload files my files from onprem server to S3 bucket and the code works, when I specify the file I want to upload.

```
import boto3
import sys, ast
import io
import os
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json
from pprint import pprint
import urllib.request
import traceback
from datetime import datetime


accesskey = sys.argv[1]
secretkey = sys.argv[2]
sessiontoken = sys.argv[3]
kmskeyid = sys.argv[4]
filepath = sys.argv[5]
s3bucket = sys.argv[6]
s3key = sys.argv[7]

try:
    s3_client = boto3.client(
        's3',
        aws_access_key_id = accesskey,
        aws_secret_access_key = secretkey,
        aws_session_token = sessiontoken,
        region_name="us-east-1"
    )
except Exception as e:
    print("[ERROR]\nFAILURE CREATING S3 CLIENT!")
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)

def upload_file_to_s3():
    #s3_client.upload_file(version + '.zip', s3bucket, s3key,ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms", "SSEKMSKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:XXXX"})
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as code:
        s3_client.upload_fileobj(code, s3bucket, s3key,ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms", "SSEKMSKeyId": kmskeyid})


try:
    print('Uploading object to S3 bucket: ' + s3bucket + "/" + s3key)
    upload_file_to_s3()
    print("[INFO]\nFile successfully uploaded to S3.")
except Exception as e:
    print("[ERROR]\nFAILURE UPLOADING TO S3!")
    traceback.print_exc()
    sys.exit(1)
```

Command that I'm running from my onprem server:

```
python3 ./scripts/python/upload_file_to_s3_min.py $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN $AWS_KMS_KEY_ID *.zip* $AWS_BUCKET deploy/scripts/
```

Error message:

```
Uploading object to S3 bucket: file2.zip/file3.zip
[ERROR]
FAILURE UPLOADING TO S3!
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

For some reason the script doesn't pass the $bucketname

Thanks,

Comment: I'd say that your shell is expanding the *.zip* argument which is populating your sys.argv[5] variable.

Answer (score 0):

Some general feedback...

People typically store their AWS credentials in a configuration file. This can be done by using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and running the `aws configure` command.

Once the credentials are saved in this manner, your code does not need to reference any credentials. They will be auto-discovered.

So, your code could be as simple as:

```py
s3_client = boto3.client('s3', region_name="us-east-1")

with open(filepath, 'rb') as code:
    s3_client.upload_fileobj(code, s3bucket, s3key,ExtraArgs={"ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms", "SSEKMSKeyId": kmskeyid})
```

If your intention is to simply call this from the command-line, then instead of writing your own script you could simply use an AWS CLI command:

```
aws s3 cp foo.zip s3://my-bucket/foo.zip --sse-kms-key-id xxx
```

Comment: Thanks John. We're using Jenkins to pass the variables. 
We dont have AWS CLI installed on the jenkins node and that's the reason why we're using the python script